# Converting array of strings into array of objects in React JS

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have an array as,

```
const headArray = ['id', 'correlationId', 'category', 'subCategory'];
```

I want to convert this as below,

```
    const columns =  [{ field: 'id', headerName: 'id'},
                      { field: 'correlationId', headerName: 'correlationId'},
                      { field: 'category', headerName: 'category'}
                      { field: 'subcategory', headerName: 'subcategory'}];
```

I tried many ways but I couldn't do this. If anyone know the method please tell me.

Comment: This is not JSON. Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to achieve this :

`const columns = headArray.map(value => ({field: value, headerName: value}));`